# Convert List<object> to JSON

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using spring data jpa to fetch data from database.I written code for that in repository interface .But I am getting jpql output in below format:

```
[[21632,"Allfrey Laboratory","110060"],[21633,"Allis Laboratory","110070"]
```

But i want this output in json format like:

```
[{"ndept_id":21632,"sdept_name":"Allfrey Laboratory","ninst_id":60,"bis_locked":false,"sclient_dept_id":"110060","nsurvey_method_id":1,"bis_jointuse":false,"ntemp_dept_id":4,"balternate_jointuse_percentage":false,"ndiv_id":null}]
```

**DepartmentRespository**

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> 
{
    @Query("select d.ndept_id,d.sdept_name,d.sclient_dept_id from Department d")
    public List<Department> findColumns();
}
```

**DepartmentController**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/findcolumn", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List <Department> findColumnData()
    {
        return departmentservice.getColumns();
    }
```

Comment: Where this jpql output come from? Is this  the result of the `toString` method on Department? Show us the code of your `Department` class. If I understood correctly, you only need to create a DepartmentDTO with the fields that you want and return it on the Controller (instead of return the Department).

Answer (score 1):

I am using spring data jpa to fetch database data .For that i used jpa query in the repository interface .By using above query i am not able to get fetched output in proper format.I want that output in json.
For that i added `new map` in select statment. And i resolved my error.

**Update:**

```
@Repository
    public interface DepartmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> 
    {
        @Query("select new map(d.ndept_id,d.sdept_name,d.sclient_dept_id) from Department d")
        public List<Department> findColumns();
    }
```